# How to i print the result from the readline() method

Tags: java

I’m trying to print out the result from the `readline` method in a certain format.  I also need to add two more `if` statements, but I’m not sure how to get the code to continue through them if the previous one is true.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String csvFile = args[0]; //name of our csv file
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    String[] columns = new String[6];
    String columnLine = "";
    float notToBeBelow = 12;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        if ((columnLine  = br.readLine()) != null) {
            columns = columnLine.split(cvsSplitBy);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                String[] routerInfo = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                if (routerInfo[2].toLowerCase().equals("no")) {
                    float OSVersion = Integer.parseInt(routerInfo[3]);
                    if(OSVersion >= 12) {

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `System.out.println()`?

Comment: Do note that from your code, if `String[] routerInfo = line.split(cvsSplitBy);`, the array could be smaller than 2, on a line without commas for instance, and `routerInfo[2]` would throw a [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
if (condition) {

} else {
   if (condition2) {}
   else {}

   if (condition3) {}
   else {}
}
```

You can place an if inside the `else` of another one.